# Where to find tutorials on createJS/easelJS

Tags: easeljs, createjs

I can't seem to find any tutorials except those present in the master.
Does anyone have any recommendation, anything would help websites/books/youtube videos ?

Comment: Hi, today is 2018, I have also been searching through the net for good tutorial but having the toughest time. Did you find any good tutorials that you can share?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you visited the [EaselJS website](http://www.createjs.com/#!/EaselJS)?  Under learning resources, you can find official and community tutorials and a getting started video.

Hope that helps.